# Making a column-based grid into a row-based grid

Tags: html, css

I have a grid that has three columns using this template: `grid-template-columns: 70px auto 70px;`

[Ignore the colors. They're just for contrast.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4obTi.png)

What I want is to have the columns resize into rows upon a `@media-query (max-width: 700px)` with the same size.

If this is a common question, I apologize — I must be searching the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) here. Then all you'd need to do is set `flex-direction: column` to flip the axis.

Comment: Anonymous -1, why do you hate flexbox?